# MacBook cooler fan ripped wires

Tags: macbook-pro, repair

Due to a mishap during disassembly, I managed to rip the cooler fan's wires from the on-board connector. The connector itself appears intact, as do the ends of the wires. Is there a way of re-inserting the wires into the connector? It's a 2010 model A1278.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plastic connector is probably broken given that they were, as you describe, ripped from the connector.  There are very tiny detente molded into the connector and these are probably broken meaning the wire will no longer be secure.  This can lead to intermittent connection problems.

Spend the few dollars and get a new fan; it’s extremely inexpensive.

Comment: This is a bit of a time-sensitive case, otherwise I'd have ordered a new one already. I examined the connector, there is no apparent damage, even under magnification, and a test-fit seems secure. The bit that bothers me is the wire positions: placing them in the wrong order will obviously lead to the fan not working. Does the Macbook have thermal cutout to protect the processor?
I'll probably order a new one anyway to be safe, but I do need this device to work sooner rather than later.

Comment: Yes.  The SMC will handle the thermal throttling and cut off if things get too hot.